# Getting an error while opening jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in 
from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 18, in 
from jupyter_client.session import Session
File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 41, in 
from jupyter_client.jsonutil import extract_dates, squash_dates, date_default
File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/jsonutil.py", line 10, in 
from dateutil.parser import parse as _dateutil_parse
File "/home/mohit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 158
l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what version is your `python-dateutil` package? `python-dateutil` version should be >= 2.0 to be compatible with python3.

Answer (score 0):

pip install python-dateutil --upgrade will solve your problem